# How to disable all explorer / shell extensions permanentely

Tags: windows-explorer, shell-extensions

Since quite a while i sometimes run into the problem that just opening a file in any application (using the open file dialog) takes some 20 Seconds each time. I tracked this down to some explorer plugins / shell extensions from dropBox. So i run Autoruns from Sysinternals (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) and just disable all explorer plugins. This works fine, until this plugin is updated - which happens quite frequently.

I dont need any of these trouble making extensions and i want to tell windows explorer just to never load them. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Dropbox, so cannot test if there is an option during its
installation for not installing shell extensions in Explorer.
You could try re-installing it to see if such an option exists.

Otherwise, the program
[ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html)
can list the troublesome shell extensions and their originating DLL
in the Filename column.

Once you find the problem DLL, you could, as Administrator, traffic
its permissions to lock it so that  the Dropbox update wizard couldn't
touch it.

(I note that I don't know whether in that case the wizard will fail
or will continue, or whether some functionality will be degraded.)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but i guess this wont work: The problem is, that each update of DropBox seems to have a DLL with a new name. currently its DropboxExt64.52.0.dll. The next would be DropboxExt64.53.0.dll etc.

Comment: Curious about this one as well, my explorer.exe slows down the laptop frequently. Perhaps one route to go would be to write a script that runs once a day, and doesn't touch whitelisted dlls, but replaces any non whitelisted ones with zero byte ones. Or actively disables them in the registry.

Comment: @REDSOFTADAIR-StefanWoe: If the DLL changes, you could perhaps prevent Dtopbox from updating that frequently, or attack the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Approved`. However, this is equivalent to redoing the delete every time that Dropbox is updated, whether via ShellExView, or a registry script, or a PowerShell script.

Comment: Well in general, i want to get rid of all these shell extensions. I just dont need them. There should be a way to tell this explorer?

Comment: Microsoft didn't supply this, so you need to sabotage something. You could perhaps delete these extensions, then traffic the permissions of the registry key so that only you could add extensions. This needs to be done with precaution, or you could cripple all shell extensions of any kind. It's perhaps worth a separate post.

Comment: Shell extensions are typically COM DLLs written in c++.  Most of them install/uninstall with a function called DLLRegisterServer and DLLUnRegisterServer.  You can probably use the `Regsvr32 /u DLLHERE` command to simply uninstall the functionality you don't want via ***shutdown*** script.  This will allow you to target the annoying ones.  If you do it in a startup script, you will have to kill and restart the explorer after un-registering.  RegSvr32 is lightning fast.